# Why is Visual Studio Code running Python when it should run Java on Mac

Tags: python, java, macos

I wrote a standard 'Hello World' Java program in a file called QuickTest.java in the latest Visual Studio Pro (on Mac).  I have installed the standard Extension Package for Java.  Which seams to have installed several required packages.

```
class Hello {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Hello, World.");
   }
}
```

And then got this error when running with F5:

```
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
```

Clearly showing that VSCode is running Python Instead of Java.

Comment: What language is your editor showing in the bottom-right corner on the status bar?  Have you saved the above code to a file with `.java` as its suffix?  Have you looked at any "Getting started with VSCode and Java" docs such as https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial ?

Comment: @GregFenton it shows Java.

Comment: Okay, but have you configured your Java project, as per the above doc (or many similar docs)?  Here's a short 5-min "getting started" video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BB0gZFpukJU

Comment: @GregFenton Oh I have another hint.  I quit the application and restarted it.  Clicked on the inner run button and that ran correctly.  The inner Debug button also worked.  So only the F5 button failed.  I'll look at the doc above.  I never got asked which compiler to use but I'll look at that document above.

Comment: @GregFenton As above I did say above I installed "Extension Package for Java."  Which installs Language Support for Java, Debugger for Java, Test Runner for Java, Maven for Java, Project Manager for Java and Intellicode.